# Is it correct to say, 'The exception is when'

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct to say, 'The exception is when' ?
For example, 'The exception is when there is a party'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Here is a quotation from the Oxford Dictionaries site, found in a discussion of a different topic:

> Direct speech within direct speech
>
> As we saw above, the rule in American English is to use double
>   quotation marks for direct speech. ***The exception is when*** a piece of
>   direct speech is quoted within another piece of direct speech, in
>   which case the internal quote should use single quotation marks.

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/inverted-commas-quotation-marks

Comment: Does your answer not miss the point of the question?

Comment: I should have thought that quoting an example of "The exception is when..." on Oxford Dictionaries directly addressed the question. Please clarify how I missed the point.

Comment: The answer, while giving an example of the construction, seems to me to be more informative about the use of quotation marks than of why it is - or is not - correct.

Comment: That is a good point.

Answer (score 0):

**No one may wear shorts to school. The exception is when there is a party.**

That's fine.